# JTabbedPane doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtabbedpane

```
    public void tabbedPane(){
        JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
            JButton btn = new JButton("Buton - 1");
            btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
            btn.setLocation(0, 10);
        tab1.add(btn);
        JTabbedPane tabPanel = new JTabbedPane();
        tabPanel.addTab("tab1", null, tab1);
        tabPanel.addTab("tab2", tab1);
        tabPanel.addTab("tab3", btn);
        tabPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 150));
        tabPanel.setLocation(50, 0);
        mainPanel.add(tabPanel);//Main panel on frame
    }
```

When I run my application, I see only tab2 and tab3 pane, and I have many issues:

- tabPanel.setLocation doesn't work
- tabPanel.addTab("tab1" ...) doesn't work
- btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20)); when I
  click "tab2" it works correctly, however when I click "tab3" it doesn't change button
  size.. why?

and i use null layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your objective with this?

A `JTabbedPane` is used to organize views, I see you're trying to add a JPanel as a first tab, this is the 'main goal' of the JTabbedPanes.

```
tabPanel.addTab("Tab 1", tab1);
```

Try to add the tab like this, you're passing a 'null' value as the icon, which must not affect at all, but if you're not using an icon, then just add the panel as a tab with the intended name.

On second adding, you're adding again the same component (tab1).

On third adding, you're trying to add a component already on a container (tab1). This will make this component to appear only in the last container you add it to. Besides, component is a `JButton`. I cannot see the goal of a `JButton` as a tab.

For the `setLocation(x, y)` issue, check the layout you're using on the container.

Again, I think the main issue here is that you're not correctly approaching your problem, or you're not using the required tools.

Answer (score 2):

> tabPanel.setLocation doesn't work

Don't use `setLocation(...)` but instead use nested components and layout managers to achieve a pleasing and easy to maintain GUI layout.

> tabPanel.addTab("tab1" ...) doesn't work

With Swing, you can only add a component to one container, that's it. The component will only show up in the last container that it was added to.

> `btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));` when I click "tab2" it works correctly, however when I click "tab3" it doesn't change button size.. why?

Again, you will want to study the layout managers

> and i use null layout

You almost *never* want to do this as this will make your application not look correct on any platform but your own and will make it very very difficult to maintain and upgrade. It is much better to use the layout managers and let them do the heavy lifting of laying out and sizing components for you.